# How to add a new computed field into knockout view model

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel, code-snippets

I am trying to compute third field in view model.I know this is not the way but just giving the following snippet for example .
Please Help

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/ASPNET/GetGroups',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var viewModel = {
            advisorGroup: ko.observableArray(data)
        };
        viewModel.advisorGroup.label = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.code + ' (' + self.cls+')';
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(viewModel));
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    }
})


<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: code, id: code }" name="GroupsSel" checked="checked">
<label data-bind="attr: { for: code }, text: label "></label>
```

Comment: So you want to add another computed observable to the viewModel variable? It should be similar to what you already have for the label field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
success: function (data) {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(item){
        item.label = ko.computed(function () {
            return item.code + ' (' + item.cls + ')';
        });
    });
    //..........
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8WqQu/1/

Or as Anders noted, you could simply do this.

```
success: function (data) {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(item){
        item.label = item.code + ' (' + item.cls + ')';
    });
    //..........
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8WqQu/2/

Comment: If item.code cant mutate (No observable), then there is no need for a computed http://jsfiddle.net/8WqQu/2/

Comment: true. but then it would be just property manipulation on a JavaScript object. :)

Comment: Which is perfectly valid here, there is no need to add a computed since the computed cant act on value change on a none observed value

Comment: yes. i was hoping to do something like this. http://fun2code.blogspot.in/2013/11/utility-function-to-make-array.html